# Instant data type change to String JsonArray Vertx

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb, vert.x, jdbc-pool

I have service proxy db call, I am sending the jsonarray over event bus through service proxy and converting the jsonArray to tuple to make DB call.

What Issue I am facing is jsonArray I received at my dbService the data-type of Instant got changed to String and data base **throwing Invalid datetime format exception.**

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so you can't just 1 to 1 send a json array as a tuple - since the tuple is meant to define what the DB is to receive

So you need to convert the data types properly - might even see this issue with integers that are encoded as strings

Comment: I don't see issue with Integer, data type for integer not changed

Comment: Your profile says principal dev.. you can do a basic type conversion from string to date time